# Faster groupby in pandas: list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am looking for a way to rewrite a pandas groupby to improve the performance as the current version would last for ages on the dataset of interest:

```
def to_df_with_lists(group, gby):
    ret_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=group.drop(gby, axis=1).columns, index=[0])
    for col in group.drop(gby, axis=1).columns:
        ret_df.loc[0, col] = list(group[col].values)
        if len(ret_df.loc[0, col]) == 1:
            ret_df.loc[0, col] = ret_df.loc[0, col][0]
    return ret_df
```

Basically, for the given groupby, it saves the values to a list. I cannot use multiple rows as I merge it with other DataFrames in the similar format, and then the lengths of all the lists are different (later I convert it to another format).

From this:

[image]

I want to get this (note that if the list would have length 1 then groupby function returns a single value, not a list containing that value):

[image]

I know that this is not really best/common way to work with DataFrames, but I haven't found format that lets me do what I want.

Example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df_sub = pd.DataFrame({'director_id': [9970, 9970, 9970, 9970, 9970], 
                       'genre': ['Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Romance'],
                       'prob': [0.041667, 0.083333, 0.166667, 0.833333, 0.083333]},
                      index=[17317, 17318, 17319, 17320, 17321])
group = df_sub.groupby('director_id').get_group(9970)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for making singleton lists atomic (which strikes me as a bad idea), the following works:

```
df_sub.groupby('director_id').agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

Whether it is much faster than your code, I cannot say (the example is too small).

Comment: Your example would return a list, not a single item in case the length of the list is 1. Otherwise, it also strikes me as a bad idea, but I haven't managed to come up with some better solution.

Comment: You don't need `lambda` function there - `.agg(list)` will do just fine

Comment: @Valeria if you really want your singleton atoms, replace the above by:

`df_sub.groupby('director_id').agg(lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else list(x))`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski True. For some reason I was doing "list" and failing, but if we want what the OP wants, then the lambda makes its way back in.

Comment: @IgorRivin It works significantly faster indeed (I have just tried it on a bigger example). I have rewritten the script so many times that I have completely overlooked such a simple version of my groupby.